# border bottom padding on a anchor tag

Tags: css, header, border, padding

I have a anchor tag inside a header and I am trying to put a border-bottom on the anchor tag, which works, however the padding at the bottom is too large and a negative padding wont work, how do I get around this?

live [site](http://anderskitson.ca/update)

**html**

```
<div id="featureText">
        <h1>Recent Works / <a href="#">All</a></h1>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
#featureText a {
    color: #414042;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #414042;
    padding-bottom: -2px; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#featureText a {
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #414042;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #414042;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
#featureText h1 a {
    /* all your other CSS... */
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```